# My build passes locally, but fails on TFS showing an error about missing moles

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, moles

I'm working on unit tests for a certain namespace, let's call it BusinessLayer.Main. Having checked in my latest changeset, I saw it fail on the TFS build despite passing on my machine. The error it shows is "The type or namespace name 'MClassX' does not exist in the namespace 'BusinessLayer.Main.Moles' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have no pending changes on my machine, so the code should be the same. What could be causing the build to behave differently on my machine and in the TFS build?

I'm using VS2010 and Moles 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

While you may not have any pending checkins, you may have a referenced file or resource that you have not added into source control. Often, these are binary files that you are adding as a reference to a project. Check to see if any of your Moles DLLs are missing from TFVC.